# Is the JavaScript array really of type map

Tags: javascript, arrays, abstract-data-type

In JavaScript you are able to place a variable or an object into an array in a various ways:

```
array.push(item)
array[2] = item;
array[somevariable] = item
```

the latter of the above example is what bothers me

say for instance that i have the following variable `var somevariable = 'someString';`

i would be able to place this into the `array` as an index (or key) if you wish.

This behavior is mostly seen in the `Map` interface suggesting that the array in JavaScript is not of the type `List`.

Another note is that the `Array object` in JavaScript also has a `pop` method which is seen in the `Queue` interface.

So my question is what data type is the `Array`in `JavaScript`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question could be simply solved opening your debugger and executing `typeof []`, which will print `object`...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Note `typeof function(){} === 'function'`, but it belongs to the Object type. `typeof` is not always a reliable way to get the type of a value, despite its name.

Comment: @Oriol For me, it's still reliable ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are just objects with some special methods and behaviors.

As objects, you can store properties in them. The key must be a string (or symbol in ES6), and the value can be anything.

However, array methods only take into account the properties whose names are array indices.

> [**15.4 Array Objects**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)
>
> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property
>   names. A property name *P* (in the form of a String value) is an
>   *array index* if and only if [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)([ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(P)) is equal to *P* and [ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(*P*) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

It's recommended to use only array indices in arrays. If you want other properties, you won't be able to use array methods with them. But then better use a normal object. Or maybe a ES6 map, whose keys and values can be anything.

The spec doesn't say how arrays should be implemented. Most implementations use some kind of list in case there are only array indices, but switch to a hash if you add other properties.

Answer (score 1):

An array is both an object and an array. That it why you can add named properties to it in the same way as you can add named properties to an object or to a function.

You can tell that an array is an object with:

```
var a = [];
console.log(typeof a);
```

will print "object"

If you need to test if a variable is actually an array you can use:

```
Array.isArray(a);
```

Comment: Just FYI, `Array.isArray()` requires a polyfill in IE <= 8, in case that matters to OP's project

Comment: A good point. It makes me so happy that so few people use old versions of IE these days.

Comment: Yea, I luckily don't support IE8 or lower now, but I know some people do, so I try to keep it in mind on SO just in case